# How to select a select option added on the client based on its value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am unable to select from options that are added dynamically by jquery. This is where l am adding the options:

```
$.get($('#baseurl').val() + '/category-products', {id : category_id}, function(response){
        if(response.success)
        {
            var product_select = $('#product_select').empty();
            $.each(response.products, function(i, product){
                $('<option/>', {
                    value: product.id.toString(),
                    text: product.name
                }).appendTo(product_select);
            });
            set_product();
        }
    });
```

This is where l am trying to select an option manually:

```
$('#product_select').val($('#pres_product').val()).change();
```

The `pres_product` is an hidden tag with the value of the option i wish to select. I have checked the value of `$('#pres_product').val()` to ensure its correct.
I have noticed that selection on a select with options that were added from the server works perfectly.

Comment: If you set the `val()` manually (instead of using `#pres_product`) - does it work?

Answer (score 0):

You should set `selected` attribute

```
$('#product_select').val($('#pres_product').val()).prop('selected', true);
```

Comment: If i add an alert before the selection line it works correctly i.e. before $('#product_select').val($('#pres_product').val()).prop('selected', true);

Answer (score 0):

```js
var newData = [{
    id: 4,
    name: 'four'
}, {
    id: 5,
    name: 'five'
}, {
    id: 6,
    name: 'six'
}];

var hiddenInput = $('#pres_product');
var product_select = $('#product_select').change(function() {
    console.log(this.value);
});

function changeOptions() {
    product_select.empty();
    var html = "";
    newData.forEach(function(d) {
        html += '<option value="' + d.id + '">' + d.name + '</option>'
    })
    product_select.html(html);
}

function setProduct() {
    val = hiddenInput.val(); //can be string also "5"
    product_select.val(val).change();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" value="5" id="pres_product" />
<select id="product_select">
    <option value="1">one</option>
    <option value="2">two</option>
    <option value="3">three</option>
</select>
<button onclick="changeOptions();">
    Change Select
</button>
<button onclick="setProduct()">
    Set New Value
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by causing a delay before selection of the item. It seems that it was not fully loaded if the selection of the value was done immediately. Below is the code:

```
 $.blockUI({ css: { backgroundColor: '#337AB7', color: '#fff'}, baseZ: 2000 });
    $.get($('#baseurl').val() + '/category-products', {id : category_id}, function(response){
        if(response.success)
        {
            var product_select = $('#product_select').empty();
            $.each(response.products, function(i, product){
                $('<option/>', {
                    value: product.id.toString(),
                    text: product.name,
                }).appendTo(product_select);
            });
        }
    });
    var delay = 1000;
    //allow for the items to have loaded properly
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#product_select').val($('#pres_product').val()).change();
        $.unblockUI();
    }, delay);
```

I noticed that accidentally when i used an alert just before trying to select. It worked well so l figured out that the items needed a little bit of time to load properly.